# Help understand a dual of an optimization problem

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

The main problem is that I don't understand why (8) is the dual of (6).

**Dual**: I think the minimization in the dual is over $p_{ij}$ and $z_i$.

> [image]

**Primal**:

> [image: ![enter image description here]

---

**Supplement**. The source of this problem is [this paper](http://www.ie.bilkent.edu.tr/~mustafap/courses/bsimor_article.pdf). The original model is

> [image]

and I understand the following proposition.

> [image]

**The problem**: I have trouble understanding the dual in the proof. I tried computing the dual function without success.

> [image]